# Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ with $\kappa (G) \geq 1$. Prove that $n> \kappa(G)[\operatorname{diam}(G)-1]+2$

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ with $\kappa (G) \geq 1$. Prove that $n> \kappa(G)[\operatorname{diam}(G)-1]+2$

I know $\kappa(G) \leq n-1$. I do not know if do we have to prove it by induction or there is another way.

Comment: Welcome to math.se. Can you explain your thought process about the problem so far?

Comment: what is $\kappa(G)$?

Comment: \kappa(G) is the connectivity of G.